# Adding a row to a table doesn't reflect in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I am trying to test an event on the DOM using jasmine and jQuery.
I simplified it to the extreme of just appending a row to a table. (I load the table and it is defined, just in case anyone suggests it is not loading, I also tried before and beforeEach)
If I do this directly on the browser console, it works:

```
jQuery("#myTableId tr").length 
//returns 0
jQuery("#myTableId").append("<tr></tr>") 
jQuery("#myTableId TR").length
//returns 1
```

But when in my tests I write:

```
it("Should have no rows in the beginning ", function () {
    expect(jQuery("#myTableId tr").length).toBe(0)
});
//WORKS because the table has no rows

it("Should add a row when I ADD A ROW ", function () {
    jQuery("#myTableId").append("<tr></tr>") 
    expect(jQuery("#myTableId tr").length).toBe(1)
});
//FAILS because it didn't append anything
```

Is this a known behaviour?
Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
For further readers, as user @flowtron pointed out:

```
it("Should EXIST ", function () {     
    expect(jQuery("#myTableId").length).toBe(1); 
}); 
//FAILS 
it("Should EXIST ONLOAD ", function () { 
    expect(jQuery(document).ready(jQuery("#myTableId")).leng‌​th).toBe(1); 
});
 //PASS
```

Comment: is the DOM definitely established - I mean, are you running this in body.onLoad ? Or in jQuery( function(){ /*here*/ } ); ??? So jQuery("#myTableId").length is != 0, yes!?!

Comment: Thanks! you are totally right, it is not loading at all, this quick hack proved the way to go!:
    it("Should EXIST ", function () {
        expect(jQuery("#myTableId").length).toBe(1);
    });
    //FAILS

    it("Should EXIST ONLOAD  ", function () {
        expect(jQuery(document).ready(jQuery("#caseListTable")).length).toBe(1);
    }
    //PASS

Answer (score 0):

Try using `before`:

```
describe('Adding a row', function(){
  before(function(){
    jQuery('#myTable').append('<tr></tr>');
  });

  it('should have 1 row', function(){
    expect(jQuery("#myTable tr").length).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: tried it, passes the 0 (shouldn') but not the 1 row

Comment: You should then check what `jQuery('#id').append` does. If possible, post your full code here.